# I have installed both ROS 1 (neotic) and 2 (galactic) but package path is the same upon checking

Tags: ros

I am new to ROS and I have been following the instructions from ROS wiki page. I installed both ROS 1 (neotic) and ROS 2 (galactic). I printed the environment information for each using:
`printenv | grep ROS`

I first tried to source (does this mean initialize an environment?) ROS 1 (neotic) using the code:`source /opt/ros/neotic/setup.bash`

and the result is:

> ROS_VERSION=1
> ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
> ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/noetic/share ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
> ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/noetic/etc/ros
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311 ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=0
> ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/noetic/share/ros ROS_DISTRO=noetic

But when I source ROS 2 using the code`source /opt/ros/galactic/setup.bash` and printed the environment information, the output is:

> ROS_VERSION=1 ROS_PYTHON_VERSION=3
> ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/noetic/share ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
> ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/noetic/etc/ros
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311 ROS_LOCALHOST_ONLY=0
> ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/noetic/share/ros ROS_DISTRO=noetic

Can you enlighten me about this? It seems like the ouput is from the bash file but how can I make sure that ROS 1 would not mix up with ROS 2?

Comment: That should not be the case. As a first step I would check the installation path of ROS2, then check if your `.bashrc` still sources the ROS1 environment and could therefore interfere with you sourcing ROS2 later on. Some variables are unused in ROS2 but `ROS_VERSION` and `ROS_DISTRO` should still be used.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but then I found out that I was using the same terminal to source foxy after sourcing noetic. Closing the terminal after sourcing a version of ROS then opening a new terminal and sourcing the second version solves the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).